# json.net how do i parse to object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

i tested the json before i get result 
but tried to get more clear with this but it doesn't work

i don't need other solution to get table[0].id
i want to know how to add all data to object

```
       {"table:[{"name":"ali","id":"1","id_f":"1","x":"11","y":"10","r":"0","w":"100","h":"100"}]}




 public class Table
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string id_f { get; set; }
        public string x { get; set; }
        public string y { get; set; }
        public string o { get; set; }
        public string w { get; set; }
        public string h { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Table> table { get; set; }
    }

       RootObject aa = new RootObject();
        aa=JToken.Parse(result).ToObject<RootObject>();//result is the json data
        ttt.Text = aa.table[0].id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`:

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result)
```